# Sorting datagridview column as numeric with N2 formatting

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, format

I have a datagridviewcolumn that has decimal values in it. I want to show the values with commas and decimal points so I am using .format("N2") to display them. However, now I can't sort the column anymore (by clicking on the column header) because it is no longer seen as numeric values but rather as character values.

Is there a way to keep the numeric values so I can sort and still have the formatting?

Edit:
The values are first put into an array by reading the in from a database. Then I add the values to the grid like this:

results_grid.Rows.Add(search_results(x).toString("N2"))

Comment: Yes there is, but it depends on how the data got into the DGV.  Are you using DataBinding? Show how you are *using .format("N2") to display them* because thats where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If I set the whole column to the format rather than the individual items, it works as expected.

So now, I'm using:

```
results_grid.Columns.Item(5).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n2"
```

and it sorts numerically.